# Incorrect boolean value is being sent across socket python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I might be making a very basic error here so sorry, but when I send data across my socket from my server to my client, I receive a different value on the client.
The value should be False, but instead I get a True

Server:

```
playerMoved = chessGame.movePossible(mousePos, prevCol, prevRow)
playerMoved = str(playerMoved)
print(f"Player Moved = {playerMoved}")

conn.sendall(playerMoved.encode(FORMAT))
```

Client:

```
playerMove = self.socket.recv(3)
playerMove = playerMove.decode(self.format)
playerMove = bool(playerMove)
# Get back board
if playerMove:
   print(f"Player move turned out to be true")
   self.chessBoard = self.receiveBoard()
```

And here is what is printed.

From the client:
[image]

From the server: [image]

Again, I might be making a silly error here, but I can't find anything that is wrong. Thanks for looking anyway!

EDIT:
A user in the comments told me to print(playerMove), so I changed the client code to:

```
    playerMove = self.socket.recv(3)
    playerMove = playerMove.decode(self.format)
    playerMove = bool(playerMove)
    # Get back board
    if playerMove:
       print(f"Player move turned out to be true")
       self.chessBoard = self.receiveBoard()
```

And it still says true.
[image]

Even though the server says false:
[image]

Ohh, a user down below (same one as before) made me look at what the code says before I decode it and convert it to a bool. This is what I get, the False is being cut off.

[image]

Comment: why don't you `print(playerMove)`?

Comment: @user253751 i've changed the code (and updated the post), it still prints True. Thanks for trying to help though :)

Comment: Yeah but *before* decoding it and *before* converting it to bool. What is your program actually sending and what is it actually receiving? Sockets send bytes, not bools

Comment: @user253751 i've checked what the program is sending (which is what the server sends), I'll check what it is before converting it to bool, and decoding it, check my post in a few mins as I'll update it

Comment: and what the server is sending after encoding it

Comment: @user253751 yeah you were right, when I check before, the False is cut off, I know the issue now

Comment: @user253751 post your second comment as an answer, and I'll tick it as the answer. I had to change how many bytes I was receiving, I said to receive 3 which cut it off.

Comment: I can't take credit for that one, you solved it yourself, but I really wonder *why* you didn't think to look at the data that was being sent and received through the socket...

Comment: @user253751 I'm not sure, I had already spent hours on this, and I was just mentally exhausted